# How can I take all "Source" changes from merge conflicts in VS 2019?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I need to merge a remote branch with my local branch, and there are over 700 conflicts that need to be resolved. I would like to take the "Source" code instead of "Target" for each conflict, but I don't see a way to do this in bulk.  I've seen that previous versions of visual studio let you select multiple options in this resolve conflicts menu, but is that not available for 2019?  Is there an alternate way to handle merge conflicts so that I can select the files from the source for every conflict?

[image: Merge Conflicts]

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using the following two commands in a git command prompt:

`git checkout --theirs .`

`git add .`